# Stream multiple huge .tar.gz files into one file

Tags: tar, gzip, streaming

I have a three .tar.gz files, and I need them all to be compressed into one .tar.gz file.

After some googling I found the `--concatenate` option for `tar`, but that requires the files to be uncompressed first, and my hard drive isn't large enough to hold one of these unzipped files, let alone three (they are each around 50GB in their compressed form).

Is there some bash magic that will let me stream these files in-memory into a final compressed result on my hard drive?

Comment: What's your end goal, to merge the files, or to have them just stored as one file? You could potentially just `tar` all three of them so it's one big file, then you can break it apart later if needed.

Comment: I strongly recommend not to use the `gtar` specific concat option since `gtar` does not check whether the archives use a compatible set of extensions.

Comment: @cutrightjm Unfortunately a tar of tars will not work, it really does need to be one correctly merged tar. The tarball is input into some proprietary bioinformatics software, so I don't have control over the input format.

Comment: Can you potentially move one file to a different partition while you work on the other two?

Comment: @cutrightjm I could do that, if you have a solution that merges two tarballs I can use it twice to merge three tarballs. What I really need to avoid is having a full, uncompressed tarball at any point during the operation, because that exceeds my disk space.